# TypeError when calling method in TypeScript Class Inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm working on a Node.js application using TypeScript, where I have a base controller class (BaseController) and a derived controller (SettingController). The derived controller is supposed to use methods from the base class, but when calling the Ok method from an instance of the SettingController, I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Ok')

**Code:**
SettingController.ts:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
// ... other imports

export default new class SettingController extends BaseController {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    async SettingOTP(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        try {
            // ... Some operations
            return this.Ok(res, 'OTP setting updated successfully');
        } catch (error: any) {
            this.BadRerquest(res, error.message);
        }
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

**BaseController.ts:**

```
import { Response } from 'express';
// ... other imports

    export class BaseController {
    
        // ... constructor and other methods
    
        Ok<T>(res: Response, message: string) {
            return new SuccessResponse(message).send(res);
        }
    }
```

**Attempts:** I've ensured that the BaseController is properly imported and that the Ok method is defined and not overridden. I've tried binding the methods in the constructor of the SettingController, and I made sure TypeScript compilation has no issues.

**Question:** Why am I encountering a TypeError when calling this.Ok in the SettingController method, and how can I resolve this issue to properly use inherited methods in TypeScript?

**Update**

```
import express, { Express, Router, NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

import SettingController from '../../http/controller/SettingController';

// const setting_controller = new SettingController(new SettingService());

const settingRouter = express.Router();
// settingRouter.get('/get', settingController.getSetting);
settingRouter.put('/opt-setting', SettingController.SettingOTP);
```

Comment: Almost certainly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work. How are you **calling** `SettingOTP`? (Which is the only place you try to access `Ok` in the provided code.)

Comment: Thanks for showing how you call `SettingOTP`. Yup, the problem is `settingRouter.put('/opt-setting', SettingController.SettingOTP);` You're not doing anything to ensure `this` is set correctly when the function is called. See the questions linked above. (But basically, it'll be: `settingRouter.put('/opt-setting', SettingController.SettingOTP.bind(SettingController));` or `settingRouter.put('/opt-setting', (...args) => SettingController.SettingOTP(...args));`. I'd also recommend not using the initial capital letter on `SettingController`, since it's not a class, it's an *instance*.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder could you tell me advance way ? my mean in the real and large projects ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you're asking there. It's not unusual to need to do either of the two things I showed above, regardless of project size...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to know how what I am doing is implemented in big projects?

Comment: There are too many different way to do it to really say. FWIW, I don't usually use classes for Express.js middleware, but that doesn't mean it's at all wrong to do so.

Answer (score -1):

You should just have `export default class SettingController extends BaseController` not `export default new class SettingController extends BaseController`

Comment: Really that depends on whether they want to export the class or a single instance of it. But this (which may be correct) doesn't seem to address the symptom the OP asks about.

Comment: i changed to this code `export default class SettingController extends BaseController` but i faced problem here : `settingRouter.put('/opt-setting', SettingController.SettingOTP);` , `Property 'SettingOTP' does not exist on type 'typeof SettingController'.ts(2339)
`

Comment: Mr Coder, You don't need to change your code, Please update the question with the route code, how are you calling the `SettingOTP` function?